# How do I click on this button on my webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net, button, click, browser

```
<input type="submit" class="btn">
```

I can't seem to make it click on it using vb.net. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net or the .Net Web Object?  Really need more info.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the .NET WebBrowser control? If so, try something like...

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = "btn" Then 
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
Next
```

Comment: yeah, what he said. I was writing just the same as this, answer discarded and +1 given :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("btn").InvokeMember("Click")
```